# Parsing Array JSON response using SSJS activity in the automation. not giving any output- Parsing array inside the array

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, ssjs, automationstudio

```html
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
  try{
  
  var newpay = Stringify({"failedRecords":[
    {
      
       
      ],
      "offerid": "HM6T7jc9Fj2G9tx",
      "smsTemplateFields": [
        {
          "templateFieldKey": "smsTxnParam1",
          "templateFieldValue": "ABC"
        },
        {
          "templateFieldKey": "smsTxnParam2",
          "templateFieldValue": "ABC"
        },

        {
          "templateFieldKey": "smsTxnParam3",
          "templateFieldValue": "ABC"
        }

      ],
      "emailTemplateFields": [
        {
          "templateFieldKey": "emailTxnParam1",
          "templateFieldValue": "ABC"
        },
     {
          "templateFieldKey": "emailTxnParam2",
          "templateFieldValue": "DEFGHJ"
        },
     {
          "templateFieldKey": "emailTxnParam3",
          "templateFieldValue": "DSFSAFFSH"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]});

     var test = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(newpay);
var sucessfullrecords = test.successfulRecords;
var another = sucessfullrecords[0];
Write(another.offerType);
    
     
 
                  </script>

  <script runat="server">
  }catch(e){
    Write(Stringify(e));
  }
</script>
```

***able to Print offer type but now issue is " userFields" which is an array, need help to parse this and wanted to print "userFieldsValue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the userFieldsValue of every entry in that array you need to loop through it. So in your code (for the first successful record, that you have written to the "another" variable) it works like this:

```js
for (var i=0; i<another.userFields.length; i++) {
    Write(another.userFields[i].userFieldsValue);
}
```

If you like to output these values for every successful record, it looks like this:

```js
for (var i=0; i<test.successfulRecords.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<test.successfulRecords[i].userFields.length; j++) {
        Write(test.successfulRecords[i].userFields[j].userFieldsValue);
    }
}
```

*Note:* If the JSON format isn't stable, you should also add checks if the property you like to access is defined first.